# nginx : How to append a default file name and extension to a location

Tags: nginx

I use nginx as a proxy server to forward some request ( `location /mnt/`) to a dedicated upstream :

```
location /mnt/ {
  expires 1y;

  add_header Cache-Control public;
  add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

  proxy_pass http://imaginary/; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header cf-ray '';
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

I've added before that location a rewrite rule to redirect silently (without changing shown url) `/mnt/thumbnail/xxx?yyy` to `/mnt/thumbnail?yyy`

```
location /mnt/thumbnail/ {
  rewrite ^/mnt/thumbnail/(.*)$ /mnt/thumbnail last;
}
```

This is working as expected. But might not be the best way to do it.

I can't figure a way to set a permanent redirection to append `/image.jpg` to request made to `/mnt/thumbnail?yyy` like a kind of index page if no filename ends path.
All my attemps failed with `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/mnt/thumbnail/image.jpg"` or 404.

[EDIT]
I manage to have both redirect 301 and proxy forwarding. I had to replace the rewrite by a proxy_pass to forward and then I could add a rewrite to append /image.jpg if missing.

```
location = /mnt/thumbnail {
  rewrite ^/mnt/thumbnail?(.*)$ /mnt/thumbnail/image.jpeg permanent;
}

location /mnt/thumbnail/ {
  proxy_pass http://imaginary/thumbnail?$args;
}
```

Comment: you can try with regex matching.

Comment: I've tried with an `=` modifier and with `~*` also like this

    location = /mnt/thumbnail {
         rewrite ^/mnt/thumbnail$ /mnt/thumbnail/image.jpg;
    }

but I get a 500 on following:
`[error] 1746#1746: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/mnt/thumbnail", client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "HEAD /mnt/thumbnail/image.jpg?**** HTTP/1.1", host: "tshirtpreviewer_web_1"`

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. If what you want is to rewrite `/mnt/thumbnail/xxx` to `/mnt/thumbnail` and `/mnt/thumbnail/` to `/mnt/thumbnail/image.jpg`, this is cyclic already.

Comment: Indeed, @dereli its somehow cyclic. Notice that the first rewrite is not changing the url, but only doing a forward proxy. The second one should be a real redirect permanent that change the url if missing file and extension name to give by default image.jpg.
I guess, using rewrite for forward proxy is not a good way and it might not be compatible with permanent redirection with default image.jpg.

Comment: I am not talking about proxy pass, both my examples are rewrite. Can you maybe update the questions with the expected results for 3 requests: `/mnt/file1.jpg`, `/mnt/thumbnail/file1.jpg` and `/mnt/thumbnail`.

Answer (score 0):

As said in edit : I manage to have both redirect 301 and proxy forwarding. I had to replace the rewrite by a proxy_pass to forward and then I could add a rewrite to append /image.jpg if missing.

```
location = /mnt/thumbnail {
  rewrite ^/mnt/thumbnail?(.*)$ /mnt/thumbnail/image.jpeg permanent;
}

location /mnt/thumbnail/ {
  proxy_pass http://imaginary/thumbnail?$args;
}
```